# I made a backup of my iPad Pro using iTunes. Can I restore that backup onto another iPad?

Tags: ipad, backup, restore

I made a backup of my iPad Pro using iTunes. The backup is on my PC not on iCloud.

The iPad broke a few days later, so I went to a store to make the AppleCare valid, we formatted it on the store.

Will I be able to restore my old backup into the new iPad?

---

Edit:

As IconDaemon pointed out it's possible and normal to restore from backup, it was reassuring to know that I could restore my backup many days before getting the replacement

Here is a screenshot of the restore screen

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can restore the backup to your new iPad. I've restored my iPad backups many times when I went from model to model, starting from the iPad1 all the way to the iPad 6th gen. Note: I don't use Windows iTunes, but I think the function is the same.

Comment: One thing to be aware of, is that a backup from a newer version of iOS won't restore onto a device with an older iOS.  Also, from a user perspective, Windows iTunes works the same as the Mac version does.